# Updating WebView URL from a Timer Class in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to change the URL in webView from within a timer class, and as soon as the timer fires, the application crashes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    Timer xxmyTimer = new Timer();
    xxmyTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
         public void run() {
             mWebView.loadUrl("http://somesite.com/");
    }
    },5000,5000);

}
```

I've been trying to solve this all day, and no matter what I try, the result is always the same - crash & burn !

Would really appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application is crashing because you are trying access or update UI element(WebView) from the TimerTask which run on separate non UI Thread.

So in current code just add [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for accessing WeView from TimerTask Thread as:

```
xxmyTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
     public void run() {
       MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() {

        @Override
         public void run() {
          mWebView.loadUrl("http://somesite.com/");

    }
});

}
},5000,5000);
```

and other option is use [Handler.postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) instead of TimerTask.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping, I did try that solution but unfortunately I am getting:"The method runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type new TimerTask()" error.

Comment: @crankshaft : use  `MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread` instead of ` this.runOnUiThread` check updated answer

Comment: Brilliant, yes I worked that out and was about to amend my original comment, thanks sooo much, it's working.